# how to find website address from ftp address

Tags: html, url, testing, upload, ftp

I have the FTP URL of a client but I need to test the files that I uploaded through ftp. I want to open the website where the output is visible.
How can I find the URL where output is visible given the FTP URL?

Comment: Where did you get the FTP address from? Can't you ask the source of the FTP information?

Comment: At the moment the source is not replying. I'm under time pressure and would like find it out without waiting for the source.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a way to do it.

You could try pinging the FTP address, and putting the IP you get in a Reverse IP Lookup tool [like this one](http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx), but you may not have much success.